# How to generate LaTeX table in R with tabs?

Tags: r, latex, xtable

I am generating some LaTeX tables using `xtable`. I'd like to make it so that when I copy and paste the generated table it would look "lined up" in my LaTeX file. Right now I have:

```
> library(xtable)
> x <- data.frame(matrix(1:6, nrow = 2))
> xtable(x)
% latex table generated in R 3.1.2 by xtable 1.7-4 package
% Fri Jan 23 09:25:22 2015
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{rrrr}
  \hline
 & X1 & X2 & X3 \\
  \hline
1 &   1 &   3 &   5 \\
  2 &   2 &   4 &   6 \\
   \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
>
```

How can I make the table (at least the 2 rows with real data) look like this? Here all the white spaces before and after `&` are tabs.

```
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{rrrr}
    \hline
        &   X1  &   X2  &   X3  \\
    \hline
    1   &   1   &   3   &   5   \\
    2   &   2   &   4   &   6   \\
   \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hackish, but it should work:

```
library(xtable)
x <- data.frame(matrix(1:6, nrow = 2))
xtab = capture.output(print(xtable(x)))

library(stringr)
tab.xtab = str_replace_all(xtab, pattern = " +\\& +", "\t\\&\t")

# one of these should work, depending on where this is going
cat(tab.xtab, sep = "\n")
paste(tab.xtab, collapse = "\n")
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you know why the first row (1, 3, 5) is not indented by `xtable`?

Comment: Not a clue. Since whitespace doesn't matter much when compiling tex, my guess is the author didn't care much about the inconsistency.